# Drag and Drop from list to table Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I have a tool that has a list items and table ,I want to drag the items from the list and drop it into the table cells in the other side I want to drag it from the table to the same list again.I am using draggable and droppable Jquery ui .
my problem is I can't drag the items to the list after dropped it to the table cells again.
and that's my code :

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
  tolerance: 'intersect',
  drop: function (event, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this));
    $(this).addClass("withoutStyle");
  }
});
$(".draggable").draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  scroll: false,
  helper: "clone",
  stack: ".droppable"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solve:it's by make that ,
 $('#tblname').addClass('droppable');